# Ubiquiti USG & Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

could somebody help me out with the following issue?

My ISP is providing me with a static IP and a hardware only modem (1 RJ45 output). This goes to my switch and from the switch, it goes to my USG. The switch before the USG is needed cause my TV setup box needs an IP from my provider to provide digital services.

If I set up port forwarding I am able to reach internally my devices but I can not reach them from outside the network. What is the proper way in the USG to setup port forwarding so I can reach my devices from outside the network.

Setup: Modem (Static IP) -> Switch 1 -> USG WAN1 -> USG LAN1 -> Switch 2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's a "hardware only modem", and is the public IP address configured on the modem or on the USG?

Comment: @grawity the public ip address is configured on the modem

Comment: Is that mandatory or can you change it to belong to the USG (i.e. switch the modem to "bridge" mode?) Does the modem already have port forwarding rules or DMZ configured?